# Jquery datatable is not a function?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have gone through a lot of articles and sorry for a repeated question ,I know I am doing a silly mistake and not able to find out the same, below is my code block, could you please let me know what am I missing here

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table1').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why you're including jQuery three times and Datatables twice? O.o

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are including jquery.min.js more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you used multiple jquery and datablejs.

Keep only one jquery file and and put your datablejs below the jquery js.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
   {
        $('#table1').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```